# Verificar qual TextField está chamando textFieldDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, swift

Tenho vários textFields na minha tela e gostaria de saber qual deles começou uma ação.

Por exemplo:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField // aqui eu não sei comparar para ver qual textField iniciou essa chamada
}
```

Posso utilizar o Outlet de cada textField ou há outra maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Não sei se há forma mais eficiente que não seja criar estas condições a partir do `IBOutlet` referente a cada `UITextField`. Exatamente como você descreveu.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues, está certo, vou fazer dessa forma mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, você pode utilizar o Outlet para fazer essa verificação.

Basicamente você faria isso:

```
@IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

 if textField == text1 {
    print("Text 1 mudou");
 } else if textField == text2 {
    print("Text 2 mudou");
 } else {
    print("outro text mudou");
 } 
}
```

Outra maneira que você pode fazer isso é verificando a tag do UITextView. Por exemplo, levando em consideração que text1 tem a tag '1' e text2 com a tag '2' o código ficaria assim:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
 @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!

     func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        if(textField.tag == 1) {
            print("Text 1 changed");
        } else if(textField.tag == 2) {
            print("Text 2 changed");
        } else {
            print("Text ?? changed");
        }
    }
```

Levando em consideração ambas as formas, é possível observar que através do Outlet o código fica mais legível.

Edit: Conforme complemento do Luis, também é possível utilizar constantes para realizar a comparação das tags, como no exemplo:

```
let kTextField1 = 1;
let kTextField2 = 2;

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    if(textField.tag == kTextField1) {
        print("Text 1 changed");
    } else if(textField.tag == kTextField2) {
        print("Text 2 changed");
    } else {
        print("Text ?? changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pode-se criar constantes para cada `textField` e usa-las na comparação com a `tag`, assim ficaria claro da mesma forma a qual `textField` você está se referindo e não percisaria dos `Outlets`

Comment: Sim, também existe essa possibilidade Luis, obrigado pelo seu complemento! Só que se ele for utilizar o Outlet em outra parte, aí complicaria mais na minha opinião.

Comment: Concordo, eu acho a maneira comparando diretamente o objeto com o `outlet` a mais clara, inclusive utilizei ela em um form e encadeei uns 10 `if/else` porque não encontrei maneira melhor.

Comment: @LuisHenrique quando voce tiver muitos "else if" pode ter certeza que o ideal pra estes casos é o switch. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35691147/2303865